How to select an <em> html element that is Not a child of any <p> element?
/* CSS */
em {font-style: italic; background yellow}
::autonomous-not-child-of-a-p-element-? :: em {font-style:normal; background gray}

Given two situations both using <em> differently, in need to be styled differently.
The first case contains a paragraph element and within it one or multiple <em> italic styled words:
<p>...</p>
<p>A paragraph with a <em>word or two</em> in italic emphasis within the paragraph.</p>
<p>...</p>

The second paragraph contains a <em> wrapping over an entire paragraph, becoming itself a paragraph, that needs to be styled differently:
<p>...</p>
<em>An entire paragraph in its entirety in italic emphasis.<em>
<p>...</p>

Is there a way to restyle the last <em> differently automatically, when it spans an entire paragraph and is not a child of a <p> element?

You can use hierarchy/inheritance in css to target the em in p tag and normal em element to target the em tag.


em { color: #F0F; }
p em { color: #F00; }
<p>...</p>
<p>A paragraph with a <em>word or two</em> in italic emphasis within the paragraph.</p>
<p>...</p>

<hr />

<p>...</p>
<em>An entire paragraph in its entirety in italic emphasis.<em>
<p>...</p>



Also, this can be helpful to understand.
Hope, this helps.

in order to solve this issue. You can simply use the not selector to select every em element that is not a child of a p element.
If you have issues with this answer or if I didn’t totally answered it, let me know !
:not(p) > em {
    properties
}


Thanks for this elegant answer, since it does not rely or depend for an <em> element to be preceeded or followed by an <p> element and rather focuses on the key essential aspect of the question, which is when <em> is indeed NOT a child of a  element. I will try ou this solution and report back soon.

Perfect, I may got your question wrong in the first place so don’t bother telling me !

So if you have only these two conditions then you can try this solution
Solution

This will target only the child of p tag
p>em {
color: #ff0000;
font-size:30px;
}

If em is below  tag then this code will target every em that is below  tag
p+em {
color: #ff0000;
font-size:30px;
}




with the help of Specificity, you can describe the Css like:

    em {font-style:normal; background: gray}
    p em {font-style:italic; background: white}


using CSS next-sibling combinator (+) :

    p + em {font-style:normal; background: gray} /* this will select em next to P tag */


providing class name

refer:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.php
